# CRM 2016 html page 500 - internal server error

Tags: dynamics-crm, internal-server-error

In dynamics CRM 2016 I have a custom button that opens up a HTML WebResource and runs some JavaScript.
It works perfectly in our development environment.

However, in our pre-production it gives the message:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

F12 Debugging only provides the same message, and i cannot access the specific resources (the code) because it is a managed solution in preproduction.

Google only return very general "500 error fixes", or similar questions that have not been answered, that are very old.

Any suggestions how to go about this?

(And yes I have checked that it is actually pointing at the correct files).

Comment: Can you try to use the Preview of your WebResource? If you have access to the Windows Event Logs you can try to find out more about the server side error.

Comment: As the next step, try to run Event View on the server and look for the detailed error. If nothing found, you can enable tracing in CRM.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in the RibbonWorkbench in the Url command the path called, begins with `/Udv/WebResources/myPage.htm`, which is a hardcoded part of the development path.

The answer was to change the parameter to `$webresource:myPage.htm`